# Selenium WebDriver: Determining if new window or tab has opened and if it has focus

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Newbie here to using Selenium WebDriver and have searched this forum for answers or similar questions but no luck.

I'm attempting to develop automation that tries to determine when clicking on a web page link if a new window or tab has opened and if so, is the new window or tab in focus or not.

It's important to be able to determine if it is a window or a tab that has opened.  I am familiar with using driver.getWindowHandles before and after the click to determine if something opened but cannot find anything on determining if it was a window or a tab that opened.

Also, I know about using driver.getTitle but it returns the title of the parent window only.  I cannot uncover anything on determining if the newly opened window or tab is in focus or not.

Would anyone be able at least point me in the right direction on if it is possible to handle these two issues?

Comment: Does the new window/tab have different title when you open it by clicking the link manually?

Comment: Yes, it will have a different title when clicking th link manually.

Answer (score 1):

First of all,

> Also, I know about using driver.getTitle but it returns the title of
>   the parent window only.

This means you didn't switch to new window. You need to switch to new window and then verify the title.

Here is the approach to achieve both the things:

1. Save current window handle using `driver.CurrentWindowHandle`
2. Click on the link to open new window
3. Now, save all the window handles in a list
4. If count of window handles is greater than 1, you can say new window has been opened.
5. Switch to new window using `SwitchTo()`.
6. Verify the title of the new window to check whether new window is in focus or not.

Try this simple C# Code, I wrote the same against Chrome, but should work for all the browsers.

```
[Test]
    public void MultipleWindows_Test()
    {
        IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(@"CHROME DRIVER PATH");

        //Navigate to URL for ex. http://www.w3schools.com/js/
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(@"http://www.w3schools.com/js/");
        driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();

        //Get Parent Window Handle
        string parentWindow = driver.CurrentWindowHandle;

        string newWindow = "";
        string expectedNewWindowTitle = "Tryit Editor v2.6";

        Thread.Sleep(2000); //Static wait is not recommended
        Console.WriteLine("Parent Window Title: " + driver.Title);

        //Click on the link to open new window
        IWebElement TryItYourselfLink = driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("Try it Yourself »"));
        TryItYourselfLink.Click();

        Thread.Sleep(2000); //Static wait is not recommended

        //Store all window handles in a list
        IList<string> allWindowHandles = driver.WindowHandles;

        //If allWindowHandles.Count is greater than 1 then you can say that new window has been opened.
        if (allWindowHandles.Count > 1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("New window has been opened.");
        }

        //Get new window handle
        for (int i = 0; i < allWindowHandles.Count; i++)
        {
            if (allWindowHandles[i] != parentWindow)
            {
                newWindow = allWindowHandles[i];
            }
        }

        //Switch to new window handle.
        driver.SwitchTo().Window(newWindow);

        Console.WriteLine("New Window Title: " + driver.Title);

        //You can verify the title of new window to verify whether is in focus or not.
        Assert.AreEqual(expectedNewWindowTitle, driver.Title);
     }
```

I hope it helps. Let me know if it doesn't.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!  I will try this out.  Also, would you have any idea on how to determine if what opened was a window or a tab?

Comment: @Mike Sorry I couldn't get back to you. Any luck on determining the opened window or a tab?

Answer (score 0):

> how to determine if what opened was a window or a tab?

Seems like there is no different "type" on these windows, simply different options. A way I found to check if it was a tab or window is to check window.menubar.visible. For the tab, which is a full and normal window it is true, and for the window the menu is hidden and therefore false. Same applies to window.toolbar.visible.

Works in FF and Chrome at least. Unfortunately not in IE. (Testing done in IE8, which is the version I have installed. For testing of course..)

Example:

```
if(window.menubar.visible) {
    //Tab
} else {
    //"Child" Window
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the method - WebElement activeElement()
It returns WebElement with focus, or the body element if no element with focus can be detected.

Answer (score 0):

One way of determining if the window is not a tab is to execute javascript with your driver such has:

```
public void assertIsWindow(WebDriver driver) {
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
    wait.until((ExpectedCondition<Boolean>) (WebDriver d) -> {
        return ((JavascriptExecutor) d).executeScript("return window.opener !== null && !window.menubar.visible").equals(true);
    });
}
```